# PIG - how to group by field, which has multiple entries

Tags: sql, hadoop, apache-pig

I want to be able to group by hours here, i know i will have multiple entries of hours filed. For example 11th hour like below will appear multiple times. How do i do this?

```
hour,windSpeed
11, 3.6
2 , 6.8
11, 2.5
13, 5.0
14, 8.9
11, 3.2
```

So i have this and i only want to group by hour

so for example
we'd  like `{11: 3.6, 2.5, 3.2 }`

and remanings since only one value will group to it's own

`{14: 8.9}`

`{2: 6.8}`

```
answer = FOREACH weather_data GENERATE $0 AS hour, $1 as speed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by hour

```
A = FOREACH weather_data GENERATE $0 AS hour, $1 as speed;
B = GROUP A by hour;
DUMP B;
```

If you want to aggregate then use sum

```
C = FOREACH B generate group as hour,SUM(A.speed) as Total;
DUMP C;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
A = LOAD 'data' AS (Hour:chararray, windSpeed:chararray);
B = GROUP A BY (Hour);
C = FOREACH B GENERATE
FLATTEN(group) AS (Hour), A.windSpeed
;
```

Note: This is an untested code

Comment: hmm it says schema mismatch, this is more of what i was looking for. However, @inquisitive_mind provided the sol bypassing my orginal question